# Django database query giving unexpected 'illegal double' when comparing strings

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am struggling to understand why my Django database query is failing.

My Django query looks like this:

```js
        the_firebaseUID = self.request.query_params.get('firebaseUID', None)
        this_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(firebaseUID=the_firebaseUID)
```

This generates the following query:

```js
SELECT `userprofile_userprofile`.`id`, `userprofile_userprofile`.`user_id`, `userprofile_userprofile`.`firebaseUID` FROM `userprofile_userprofile` WHERE `userprofile_userprofile`.`firebaseUID` = 4929e406-9d75-43e2-afa4-fe641f3e85f5
```

My model is:

```js
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firebaseUID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

There is a firebaseUID field entry with the value `4929e406-9d75-43e2-afa4-fe641f3e85f5`

MySQL gives the following error when running the query against the database:

```js
11:03:51 SELECT `userprofile_userprofile`.`id`, `userprofile_userprofile`.`user_id`, `userprofile_userprofile`.`firebaseUID` FROM `userprofile_userprofile` WHERE `userprofile_userprofile`.`firebaseUID` = 4929e406-9d75-43e2-afa4-fe641f3e85f5 LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1367. Illegal double '4929e406' value found during parsing 0.198 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your `the_firebaseUID` variable is saving as double. You should ensure that it is a string. This may work:

```
this_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(firebaseUID=str(the_firebaseUID))
```

And the query should be translated to:

```
SELECT `userprofile_userprofile`.`id`, `userprofile_userprofile`.`user_id`, `userprofile_userprofile`.`firebaseUID` FROM `userprofile_userprofile` WHERE `userprofile_userprofile`.`firebaseUID` = `4929e406-9d75-43e2-afa4-fe641f3e85f5`
```

Comment: The python debugger is reporting the_firebaseUID as a str but I have done as you suggest and wrap the variable in str() but this makes no difference. Django is still creating a SELECT query without wrapping the value of the_firebaseUID in quotes. If I manually edit and submit the query inserting quotes around the value of the_firebaseUID MySQL returns the error: Unknown column (for the value of the_firebaseUID).

Comment: But I think you have missespelled it. You should write `firebaseUID` and not `the_firebaseUID` at the raw SQL query

Comment: I only misspelled in my comment above I think it is spelled correctly in the code.

Comment: No idea what is happening with the first error, and why is not parsing it with quotes. But the second one, has not sense. It says like your `userprofile` table does not have a `firebaseUID` attribute. And if that is true, it should also fire when you are trying without quotes. So yes, I keep thinking you have missespelled it ;p

Comment: Well yes that's what I though but I have triple checked!

Comment: If I replace the back quotes with straight quotes around the string value in the query it works fine. I need to find out how I can make Django put quotes around the string value!

Comment: Ok, please, share the result when you achieve it, I'm curious now.